# How to run spring boot application multiple instance when get resource from config server?

Tags: spring-boot, configserver

I have Eureka server, Eureka zuul and config server.
So I write a simple microservice. Then, running on 8686 port.

So I want to run that microservice on another port.
I trying that command. But don't work.

```
java -Dserver.port=8687 -jar -Dlogging.file="bla.log" testMicro.jar --debug > "bla.log"&
```

I am confusing. Help me!

Comment: You want to run your tomcat on 8687 and eureka on 8686 but both are running on 8686. Is that what is happening ?

Comment: I want to test my load balance/Zuul/ so I should run two more than instances. I can't start new instance on another port. Because that instance get application yaml file from config server. So Dserver command don't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two ways to running your instances on different ports.

1. user assignment of random port from a specified range:

```
server:
  port: ${random.int(8080,8090)}
```

2. Set in property file from config server for **testMicro** microservice the following configurations:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      override-system-properties: false
      allow-override: true
      override-none: true
```

and then run again your jar with `-Dserver.port=8687` property